# JPA query for DTYPE

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a single table which is generated from two jpa entities (inheritance). So we have a DTYPE column generated in the database table which has entity name has values.

How do I write a jpa query to fetch data for any given entity. i.e DTYPE = 'A'?

I just tried using DTYPE in jpa query but as expected I got an error "Could not resolve property". Please let me know how to write this query.

Note - I dont want to use native query.

Update:

I have class A and subclass AA which extends A. DTYPE has two values A and AA.

When I query for A, I get all the A plus AA entities. How to exclude AA when I query for A?

Comment: I got the solution :)

I used "select * from A a where a.id not in (select aa.id from AA aa)" which inturns converts to sql query select .... not in (select id from table t where t.DYPE = 'AA')

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a simple field dtype in your parent class.

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String dtype;
```

And so, you can use it in your JPQL query

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have three entities:

- Party (superclass)
- Person (extends Party)
- Organization (extends Party)

where the last two are the two entities you store with a discriminator column, your JPA-QL query should be as simple as:

```
select p from Person p
```

to get all people. JPA is smart enough to figure it out. Likewise you can do:

```
select p from Party p
```

and get all of them.

Comment: Cletus, When you query for Party how to exclude Person?

Comment: @tom_987: you don't query for Party, you query for Person or Organization. Party is just the base/common type for the inherited types.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the entity names in your JPA queries, the discriminator column is abstracted away.

Suppose you have two entity classes `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`, which both inherit from `SuperClass`, then you can query for these entites like so:

```
FROM SubClassA WHERE [...]
```

or

```
FROM SubClassB WHERE [...]
```

If you want to query for both entities, use

```
FROM SuperClass WHERE [...]
```

Comment: Henning could you please read my update and respond to my query

Answer (score 1):

In addition of what @SCH post, and as that didn't directly work for me, using Oracle, I was getting an Exception saying that "dtype" was kind of a reserved keyword. I then did

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "myDType")
class abstract AbstractClass{

@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) 
private String myDType; 
[...]
```

That worked fine for me, as this way I could dynamically change the Type I want to query using a where condition instead of changing the FROM statement.