# `Unknown column 'Camera' in 'where clause` when querying inheritance entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

**--EDIT2--**

I tried to join `Inventory` with `Product` and the last error is not occured, now this error occured: `Unknown column 'Camera' in 'where clause'`

**InventoryRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Long>  {

@Query("SELECT inventory "
        + "FROM Inventory inventory "
        + "INNER JOIN inventory.product product "
        + "WHERE inventory.product.id = product.id "
        + "AND product.class = Phone "
        + "OR product.class = Camera")
    List<Inventory> findProducts();

}
```

**--EDIT--**

After following @Simo suggestion, I change the query into the following:

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Long>  {

    @Query("SELECT inventory "
            + "FROM Inventory AS inventory "
            + "WHERE inventory.product.class = 'Phone' "
            + "OR inventory.product.class = 'Camera'")
    List<Inventory> findProducts();

}
```

The original error, which is `'could not resolve property: class of'` is not occured, but the following one occured:

```
java.sql.SQLWarning: Unknown column 'productvar1_1_.product_id' in 'where clause'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:725)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:658)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings(StatementImpl.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.cleanup(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.close(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:435)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.afterCompletion(OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.afterCompletion(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.triggerAfterCompletion(HandlerExecutionChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletion(DispatcherServlet.java:1295)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.example.XAuthTokenFilter.doFilter(XAuthTokenFilter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And this is the sql:

```
2015-12-01 17:36:06.530 DEBUG 5964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        inventory0_.product_id as product_7_10_,
        inventory0_.store_id as store_id6_10_,
    from
        inventory inventory0_ cross 
    join
        product productvar1_ 
    where
        inventory0_.product_id=productvar1_.product_id 
        and (
            case 
                when productvar1_1_.product_id is not null then Tablet 
                when productvar1_2_.product_id is not null then Phone 
                when productvar1_.product_id is not null then 'Product' 
            end='Phone' 
            or case 
                when productvar1_1_.product_id is not null then Tablet 
                when productvar1_2_.product_id is not null then Phone 
                when productvar1_.product_id is not null then 'Product' 
            end='Camera'
        )
Hibernate: 
    select
        inventory0_.product_id as product_7_10_,
        inventory0_.store_id as store_id6_10_,
    from
        inventory inventory0_ cross 
    join
        product productvar1_ 
    where
        inventory0_.product_id=productvar1_.product_id 
        and (
            case 
                when productvar1_1_.product_id is not null then Tablet 
                when productvar1_2_.product_id is not null then Phone 
                when productvar1_.product_id is not null then 'Product' 
            end='Phone' 
            or case 
                when productvar1_1_.product_id is not null then Tablet 
                when productvar1_2_.product_id is not null then Phone 
                when productvar1_.product_id is not null then 'Product' 
            end='Camera'
        )
```

**--Original Question--**

I have a list of different products which I store in SQL using inheritance in JPA. What I want to do is retrieving all the products based on a certain type. But, this error occured:

```
could not resolve property: class of: com.example.Inventory [SELECT inventory FROM com.example.Inventory AS inventory WHERE TYPE(inventory.product) = 'Phone' OR TYPE(inventory.product) = 'Camera']
```

Below is my code.

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    //some code
}
```

**Phone**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Phone")
public class Phone extends Product {
    //some code
}
```

**Camera**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Camera")
public class Camera extends Product {
    //some code
}
```

**Inventory**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(InventoryPK.class)
public class Inventory {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "store_id")
    private Store store;    

    //some code
}
```

**InventoryRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Long>  {

    @Query("SELECT inventory "
            + "FROM Inventory AS inventory "
            + "WHERE TYPE(inventory.product) = 'Phone' "
            + "OR TYPE(inventory.product) = 'Camera'")
    List<Inventory> findProducts();

}
```

Comment: what version of hibernate do you use? Perhaps it is this bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4881 ?

Comment: From the log: `Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}`

Comment: Try this query: 
 @Query("SELECT inventory "
            + "FROM Inventory AS inventory "
            + "WHERE inventory.product.class = 'Phone' "
            + "OR inventory.product.class = 'Camera'")

Comment: now, this error occured: `Unknown column 'productvar1_1_.product_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: The  product and inventory table needs a column named product_id. There must be a problem with the mapping. Please post the full stack trace.  Does the same error occur if you change the query to "Select inventory from Inventory inventory" ?

Comment: See my updated question. btw, changing the query into `Select inventory from Inventory inventory` doesn't help. thanks.

Comment: Hello, the mapping seems correct. The exception is from your MySQl Database. Please set the log level to debug (or set the hibernate property "hibernate.show_sql" to "true"), to see the full sql query.

Comment: excuse me, may I know how to set the log level in Eclipse? I've searched it and didn't find it.

Comment: no.  the log level in your logging framework. log4j or logback

Comment: Sorry, don't understand why hibernate generates wrong sql. Perhaps you can ask a new question why this sql is generated? The documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-where says it is possible in this way

Comment: ok, but thanks anyway for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution I found is by adding a dedicated `Column` for `type` in the parent entity

```
@Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String type;
```

and then, you can querying it like this:

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Long>  {

    @Query("SELECT inventory "
            + "FROM Inventory AS inventory "
            + "WHERE inventory.product.type = 'Phone' "
            + "OR inventory.product.type = 'Camera'")
    List<Inventory> findProducts();

}
```

I don't think it's elegant, but at least, it works.

Source:

[How to get the DiscriminatorValue at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005383/how-to-get-the-discriminatorvalue-at-run-time)

[JPA query for DTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070866/jpa-query-for-dtype)